# How to set Date of an existing moment.js object

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Let's say I have an existing moment object:

```
var m = moment(); // this will default to now
```

and want to update it with a new Date object, but WITHOUT REPLACING the entire object. E.g. this is NOT an acceptable solution for me:

```
m = moment(new Date());
```

The only solution I can find in there docs, is using set method:

```
m.set({'year': 2013, 'month': 3});
```

but in this way we'll need to split our existing Date object into peaces like this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var newDate = moment(myDate);

var splittedDate = {
    year: newDate.get('year'),
    month: newDate.get('month'),
    date: newDate.get('date'),
    hour: newDate.get('hour'),
    minute: newDate.get('minute'),
    second: newDate.get('second'),
    millisecond: newDate.get('millisecond')
};

m.set(splittedDate);
```

But this looks ugly to me. Maybe someone can suggest a better solution?

Comment: Seems confusing for me. Why do you want to update the moment object when you can directly assign it. Instead you can do this var m = moment(); var myDate = new Date(); m = moment(myDate); Now m will have the moment object of that date.

Comment: Am using it in angular, and changing whole object will fire an event I don't need at this point

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It may be a little late, but you can transform your new date to an object (`newDate.toObject()`) and pass it to the `set` method of your previous moment object:

```
var m = moment(); // Initial moment object

// Create the new date
var myDate = new Date();
var newDate = moment(myDate);

// Inject it into the initial moment object
m.set(newDate.toObject());
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for! Should be set as correct answer.

Comment: Brilliant!, this is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 9):

- eg:1 `moment("01/01/2000", "DD/MM/YYYY")`
- eg:2 `moment("01 Jan 2000")`

for the OP, given a string formatted in a particular way, you simply pass in the string and its format to moment, such as:

`moment("01-01-2000 23:45", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")`

There are many options for the mask, these are all listed in the momentjs docs. You can even pass an array of possible masks and moment will try them all to see if it can make sense of your original string.

Comment: moment("01-01-2000 23:45", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM", true) may help avoid unexpected behaviour

Comment: interesting - not seen that switch before. So by passing that true it "requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimeters." (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). might be useful to someone, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Just use your `Date` object as parameter:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = moment(d);
```

And *voila*, your moment object is set to the same time as your Date object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Antoine, however I updated the question, I need to keep existing object.

Comment: I don't get why you don't want to create a new object, but there's no alternative to the `set` method then.

Comment: @Antoine You do not want to create very many date objects as they take up alot of memory and process slowly; For instance when working with charts or generally data matrix that includes many timestamps; Date object initialization is often a bottleneck of performance